# Silent notification on iOS not working properly on background

Tags: xcode, background, notifications, silent

I implemented silent notification in my app to run some piece of code. When I run from Xcode, it opens the app, and I put it on background.. After few seconds, I receive the push notification and everything works well.. The problem comes when I kill the app and reopen it again. After reopen it, I put it on background again and send a silent push notification.. And the piece of code just run when I bring the app back to foreground.

Resuming.. After killing the app and reopen it again, it receives the notification just in foreground.. I turned on "Background fetch" and "Remote notifications" and used the function

```
-application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

Answer (score 1):

May be in the first case the phone is on charge, but in second case is not?
Apple changed the logic of silent push notifications: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/259269?tstart=0